# Typescript error with moment range plugin

Tags: typescript, ionic2

I have included `moment js` and the `moment-range` plugin in my Ionic 2 app like so:

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
import 'moment-range';
```

This works fine and I can use them both, but Typescript gives me the following error:

**Javascript:**

```
let range = moment().range(self.weekStart, self.weekEnd);
```

**Typescript error:**

```
Error TS2339: Property 'range' does not exist on type 'Moment'.
```

I have ran the following command to try and stop this error by installing a typings file:

```
typings install moment-range --ambient --save
```

but it doesn't seem to have had any effect. Is there something else I need to do or is there a way of silencing the error?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you installed the typings file for moment as well?

Comment: Yes, I installed `moment` and also `moment-node`

Comment: You might need to include a reference at the top of your controller / provider to the typings file. I did something similar for google maps which looked like this... `/// <reference path="../../../typings/google.maps.d.ts" />`

Comment: I tried adding `/// <reference path="../../../../typings/main/ambient/moment-range/index.d.ts" />` but the error still shows :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just looked at the interfaces. You need to call

```
let range = moment.range(self.weekStart, self.weekEnd);
```

not `moment().range`

If you look at [moment-range.d.ts](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/moment-range/moment-range.d.ts) you'll see that the range method is defined on the static interface `MomentStatic`, not the instance interface `Moment`.

Comment: That works, thank you! So frustrating when it's something so simple.

Also I was using the `.toArray('days')` function but that's not in the typings file so I added `toArray (string?: string): any;` manually into there for now.

Comment: No problem. If you find what you feel is a legit error in the .d.ts file keep in mind that they accept pull requests.

Answer (score 7):

I had to do this:

```
import * as moment from "moment";
import {extendMoment} from "moment-range";
const rangeMoment = extendMoment(moment);
const range = rangeMoment.range(start, end);
```

Answer (score 3):

They only way I got this to work in "typescript": "3.4.5"

```
const Moment = require('moment');
import {extendMoment} from 'moment-range';

const moment = extendMoment(Moment);
```

Answer (score 1):

I could not get Paarth solution to work. I still got:

`Property 'range' does not exist on type 'typeof moment'.`

The solution for me was to use type assertion:

`let range = (<any>moment).range(startDate, endDate);`

Answer (score 1):

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
import { extendMoment } from 'moment-range';

const { range } = extendMoment(moment);

const timeRange = range(moment.utc([2015, 0, 1]), moment.utc([2015, 5, 1]));

for (const month of timeRange.by('month')) {
  console.log(month.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
}
```