# Moment.js plugins in Ionic2/Cordova typescript project

Tags: angular, cordova, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

In my Ionic 2 project written in Typescript I use moment.js library.
I import it using code snippet:

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
```

After I do so, in my component I can use moment normally, ie:

```
let endDate = moment(data.endDate);
```

however, now I want to use one of plugins dedicated to moment.js - moment-weekday-calc from this repo: https://github.com/andruhon/moment-weekday-calc

I've installed plugin via npm, but I am not able to make it running.
I've tried:

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
import 'moment-weekday-calc';
```

//(...) - my component's code here

```
  let test = moment().isoWeekdayCalc({
    rangeStart: '1 Apr 2015',
    rangeEnd: '31 Mar 2016',
    weekdays: [1,2,3,4,5],
    exclusions: ['6 Apr 2015','7 Apr 2015'],
    inclusions: ['10 Apr 2015']
  }); //260
```

above code throws an error:

```
Typescript Error
Property 'isoWeekdayCalc' does not exist on type 'Moment'.
```

any idea how can I use this plugin in my typescript app for ionic/cordova?

Comment: looks like your moment-weekday-calc plugin does not have a type declarations file. You will need to have that to get its methods included in `moment` namespace...similar error for another plugin [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37317101/typescript-error-with-moment-range-plugin)

Comment: unfortunately moment-weekday-calc does not come with declarations so there are 3 options for you. Use @sebaferreras approach with `any` but you won't have code completion and rest of fancy stuff, rise an issue on github for author to emit such files or simply write them yourself ;) ofc do it in form of pull request on [moment-weekday-calc](https://github.com/andruhon/moment-weekday-calc) ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since that error is just typescript complaining about `isoWeekdayCalc` not being defined in the type definition of `moment`, you can just cast it to `any` like this:

```
let test = (<any>moment()).isoWeekdayCalc({
            rangeStart: '1 Apr 2015',
            rangeEnd: '31 Mar 2016',
            weekdays: [1,2,3,4,5],
            exclusions: ['6 Apr 2015','7 Apr 2015'],
            inclusions: ['10 Apr 2015']
        }); //260
```