# Webpack & TypeScript - Include Moment.js Plugins

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, momentjs

I want to use the [JDateFormatParser](https://github.com/MadMG/moment-jdateformatparser) together with [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) in my Angular 4 application.

---

I managed to successfully install and use `Moment.js` using:
`npm install moment --save`

And add it to my `.ts` using:

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
```

I can use and execute it.

---

After that I installed the plugin using:
`npm install moment-jdateformatparser --save`

When I then wanted to use it in my code:

```
moment().toJDFString(moment.localeData().longDateFormat('L'))
```

my IDE already complained:

> TS2339:Property 'toJDFString' does not exist on type 'Moment'.

---

Having a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42884494/1342006) I tried to do it using the casting:

```
(<any>moment()).toJDFString(moment.localeData().longDateFormat('L'))
```

This resolved the error in the IDE, but during execution the console tells me:

> TypeError: **WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6_moment**(...).toJDFString is
> not a function

---

Has anyone a hint on how to use it?

Comment: Do you import moment the same way after installing the plugin? If not you may try `import * as moment from "moment-jdateformatparser";`

Comment: If it's like other plugins I've used, you may have to "register" it on the moment module. Importing both and notifying moment that there exists a plugin. That's assuming, of course, that this plugin isn't depending on singleton modules (potentially hanging off window).

Comment: @Wernerson : Thank you very much, that resolved the problem in both cases, for the IDE (now possible without casting) and the execution! If you add an answer I will accept it. Nevertheless I am asking on how to handle multiple plugins then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to import `moment-jdateformatparser` as it simply adds its functions to moment and exports `moment`.

```
import * as moment from "moment-jdateformatparser";
```

As for using multiple plugins it seems that there isn't a good solution so far or at least I haven't found a *clean* way.

One option is you import the two plugins separately and name them differently like this:

```
import * as momentJdate from "moment-jdateformatparser";
import * as momentTimezone from "moment-timezone";
```

You can merge them afterwards if you want to like this (using deepExtend):

```
let moment = {};
deepExtend(moment, momentJdate, momentTimezone);

//here you should be able to use moment().toJDFString() and moment.tz.names()
```

Neither of these options are *clean* in my opinion but they should both work. I've also never used more then one moment plugin in one file so a workaround like this may be ok.

Comment: I will ask a new question on SO if there is a better solution for using multiple plugins as I really haven't found a better one.

Comment: [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46091734/how-to-use-multiple-moment-plugins) the question if your're interested.