# How to use multiple moment plugins?

Tags: javascript, typescript, momentjs

I know I have to import the moment plugin if I want to use it. Like this:

```
import * as moment from "moment-timezone";

//here I can use moment.tr.names() etc.
```

But what if I want to use multiple plugins? I know that plugins in moment import moment, add their functionality and then export moment again. But if that's correct, how do I use multiple plugins?

One option is to import them under a different name like:

```
import * as momentJdate from "moment-jdateformatparser";
import * as momentTimezone from "moment-timezone";
```

Or I can merge them into one moment object like this (using deepExtend):

```
let moment = {};
deepExtend(moment, momentJdate, momentTimezone);

//here you should be able to use moment().toJDFString() and moment.tz.names()
```

But neither of those seem to be *clean code*. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

What works for me and I think is clean-ish to import one after the other. For example:

```
moment = require('moment-business-days');
moment = require('moment-timezone');
moment().tz('America/New_York').businessAdd(1).startOf('day').add(7, 'hours')
```

It is not ideal, because it is opaque and without understanding how node works you might think the first require is pointless. But it is clean and effective.

Comment: I do not exactely know how `moment` is built but if this actually works they should consider to change that because to someone who isn't familiar with node module caching this doesn't make sense...

Comment: I agree it is not explicit enough. It is not a caching thing, is a singleton thing.

Answer (score 0):

```js
// utils/date.js
import momentJava from "moment-jdateformatparser";
import * as momentJsTZUI from "moment-timezone";
import moment from "moment";
const momentAll = { ...moment, ...momentJsTZUI, ...momentJava };
export { momentAll };

// then in app.js

import { momentAll } from "./utils/date";
const { default: moment}  = momentAll;

console.log(moment("2013-12-24 14:30").formatWithJDF("dd.MM.yyyy"))
console.log(moment("2014-06-01T12:00:00Z").tz('America/Los_Angeles').format('ha z'));
console.log(moment().format());
```

Comment: Sure that works. Still wouldn't consider this *clean code*.